# Get "Job Wave Number" in DataStage Using "XMETA"

Tags: sql, db2, datastage

Is there a way to get the Job Wave Number of a job in DataStage - using an SQL statement on the DataStage Repo DB "XMETA"?

I was able to get some details of a job using the below statement but I couldn't find a way to get the Job Wave Number.

```
SELECT
(TIMESTAMP('01/01/1970', '00:00:00') + (XMETA_CREATION_TIMESTAMP_XMETA / 1000) SECONDS) AS CREATION_TIME,
(TIMESTAMP('01/01/1970', '00:00:00') + (XMETAMODIFICATIONTIMESTAMPXMET / 1000) SECONDS) AS MODIFIED_TIME, A.*
FROM
XMETA.DATASTAGEX_XMETAGEN_DSJOBDEFC2E76D84 AS A
WHERE
NAME_XMETA = 'Daily_Sequence';
```

In other words, is there a way to get this line through XMETA:

```
/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin $ 
./dsjob -jobinfo DS_Prj Daily_Sequence

Job Status      : RUN OK (1)
Job Controller  : not available
Job Start Time  : Fri Feb  9 16:01:06 2018

** Job Wave Number : 12 **

User Status     : not available
Job Control     : 0
Interim Status  : NOT RUNNING (99)
Invocation ID   : not available
Last Run Time   : Fri Feb  9 16:07:50 2018
Job Process ID  : 0
Invocation List : Daily_Sequence
Job Restartable : 0
```